# Building a family tree from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, object

I'm trying to build a family tree from an array of objects in javascript.
The data is stored in a MySQL database and accessed via a PHP page.

I return an array of objects from PHP to javascript as follows:
(which is basically all the entries)

```
0 : {id: 24, sheep_name: "Mick", dam: 17, sire: 16}
1 : {id: 25, sheep_name: "Wendy", dam: 17, sire: 16}
2 : {id: 26, sheep_name: "Will", dam: 0, sire: 0}
3 : {id: 27, sheep_name: "a", dam: 25, sire: 26}
4 : {id: 28, sheep_name: "b", dam: 25, sire: 26}
5 : {id: 29, sheep_name: "c", dam: 25, sire: 26}
6 : {id: 30, sheep_name: "d", dam: 25, sire: 26}
7 : {id: 23, sheep_name: "h", dam: 19, sire: 18}
8 : {id: 21, sheep_name: "f", dam: 19, sire: 18}
9 : {id: 19, sheep_name: "Karen", dam: 0, sire: 0}
10 : {id: 20, sheep_name: "e", dam: 19, sire: 18}
11 : {id: 16, sheep_name: "Bob", dam: 0, sire: 0}
12 : {id: 17, sheep_name: "Stella", dam: 0, sire: 0}
13 : {id: 18, sheep_name: "Joe", dam: 17, sire: 16}
14 : {id: 22, sheep_name: "g", dam: 19, sire: 18}
```

The final aim is to produce an HTML list as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li>a [27]
        <ul>
            <li>Wendy [25]
                <ul>
                    <li>Stella [17]</li>
                    <li>Bob [16]</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Will [26]</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So, given a starting point - id: 27 - sheep_name: 'a', how do I go about producing the data to create the list ?

I know that I'm going to have to loop through the data multiple times until no results are returned but the mechanics of it are lost on me.

The dataset isn't fixed as parents and children can be added at any time.

I have full control over all aspects of this, javascript, PHP & MySQL including the database structure.

Any pointers or suggestions gratefully received...

For reference this is a family tree of sheep and the 'starting point' is a child and the family tree then goes:

> Parents - grandparents = great-grandparents - great great grandparents - etc.

It's like a human family tree but in reverse.

*note: Dam = Mother, Sire = Father

Comment: If this is just an academic project then this structure will work. If you're trying to build actual family trees then this is hopelessly inadequate. You need a more generic graph structure in that case as things can get really crazy.

Comment: First hint: this will be much, much easier if you do it recursively.  Second hint: you want a data structure which makes lookups easy: a plain object or a Map keyed on id.

Comment: You need to think what you want to do with siblings that have the same parents... How will that render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple recursive function that creates an html string you can use:

```js
var sheep = [
{id: 24, sheep_name: "Mick", dam: 17, sire: 16},
{id: 25, sheep_name: "Wendy", dam: 17, sire: 16},
{id: 26, sheep_name: "Will", dam: 0, sire: 0},
{id: 27, sheep_name: "a", dam: 25, sire: 26},
{id: 28, sheep_name: "b", dam: 25, sire: 26},
{id: 29, sheep_name: "c", dam: 25, sire: 26},
{id: 30, sheep_name: "d", dam: 25, sire: 26},
{id: 23, sheep_name: "h", dam: 19, sire: 18},
{id: 21, sheep_name: "f", dam: 19, sire: 18},
{id: 19, sheep_name: "Karen", dam: 0, sire: 0},
{id: 20, sheep_name: "e", dam: 19, sire: 18},
{id: 16, sheep_name: "Bob", dam: 0, sire: 0},
{id: 17, sheep_name: "Stella", dam: 0, sire: 0},
{id: 18, sheep_name: "Joe", dam: 17, sire: 16},
{id: 22, sheep_name: "g", dam: 19, sire: 18}
];

function createSheepHTML(id) {
  var s = sheep.find(e => e.id == id);
  if (s) {
    var out = "<li>" + s.sheep_name + " [" + s.id + "]";
    if (s.dam || s.sire) {
      out += "<ul>";
      if (s.dam) {
        out += createSheepHTML(s.dam);
      }
      if (s.sire) {
        out += createSheepHTML(s.sire);
      }
      out += "</ul>";
    }
    out += "</li>";
    return out;
  }
}

document.getElementById("sheepGoHere").innerHTML = createSheepHTML(27);
```

```html
<ul id="sheepGoHere"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first key the objects by their id in an ES6 Map. Then use a recursive function that will:

- Look up the given id(s) in the map to retrieve the object(s) with that/those id(s)
- Skip those for which the id did not match (like for 0)
- Use recursion to build the HTMLs for the father and mother for each object, and wrap that object's HTML together with the current object's information in `li` tag
- Join these HTMLs together and wrap the result in an `ul` tag

As an optional addition, you could pass on the level of indentation.

Here is the ES6 code for that:

```js
function toHTML(sheep, id) {
    return (function recurse(map, ids, indent) {
        const html = ids.map( id => map.get(id) ) // Retrieve the sheep objects by id
            .filter(Boolean) // Remove non-matches
            .map(obj => `${indent}  <li>${obj.sheep_name} [${obj.id}]\n` +
                        recurse(map, [obj.dam, obj.sire], indent+'    ') + // Recurse
                        `${indent}  </li>\n`)
            .join('');
        return html.length ? `${indent}<ul>\n${html}${indent}</ul>\n` : '';
    })(new Map(sheep.map(obj => [obj.id, obj])), [id], ''); // Create map
}

const sheep = [{id: 24, sheep_name: "Mick", dam: 17, sire: 16},{id: 25, sheep_name: "Wendy", dam: 17, sire: 16},{id: 26, sheep_name: "Will", dam: 0, sire: 0},{id: 27, sheep_name: "a", dam: 25, sire: 26},{id: 28, sheep_name: "b", dam: 25, sire: 26},{id: 29, sheep_name: "c", dam: 25, sire: 26},{id: 30, sheep_name: "d", dam: 25, sire: 26},{id: 23, sheep_name: "h", dam: 19, sire: 18},{id: 21, sheep_name: "f", dam: 19, sire: 18},{id: 19, sheep_name: "Karen", dam: 0, sire: 0},{id: 20, sheep_name: "e", dam: 19, sire: 18},{id: 16, sheep_name: "Bob", dam: 0, sire: 0},{id: 17, sheep_name: "Stella", dam: 0, sire: 0},{id: 18, sheep_name: "Joe", dam: 17, sire: 16},{id: 22, sheep_name: "g", dam: 19, sire: 18}];
const html = toHTML(sheep, 27);
console.log(html);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object with all references to the parents and choose the the person's `id` and take the nested object.

```js
var family = [{ id: 24, sheep_name: "Mick", dam: 17, sire: 16 }, { id: 25, sheep_name: "Wendy", dam: 17, sire: 16 }, { id: 26, sheep_name: "Will", dam: 0, sire: 0 }, { id: 27, sheep_name: "a", dam: 25, sire: 26 }, { id: 28, sheep_name: "b", dam: 25, sire: 26 }, { id: 29, sheep_name: "c", dam: 25, sire: 26 }, { id: 30, sheep_name: "d", dam: 25, sire: 26 }, { id: 23, sheep_name: "h", dam: 19, sire: 18 }, { id: 21, sheep_name: "f", dam: 19, sire: 18 }, { id: 19, sheep_name: "Karen", dam: 0, sire: 0 }, { id: 20, sheep_name: "e", dam: 19, sire: 18 }, { id: 16, sheep_name: "Bob", dam: 0, sire: 0 }, { id: 17, sheep_name: "Stella", dam: 0, sire: 0 }, { id: 18, sheep_name: "Joe", dam: 17, sire: 16 }, { id: 22, sheep_name: "g", dam: 19, sire: 18 }],
    ids = {};

family.forEach(function (person) {
    ids[person.id] = Object.assign(ids[person.id] || {}, person);
    ids[person.dam] = ids[person.dam] || {};
    ids[person.id].dam = ids[person.dam];
    ids[person.sire] = ids[person.sire] || {};
    ids[person.id].sire = ids[person.sire];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(ids, 0, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```